# Fabric Crashlytics "Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating" whilst verifying install

Tags: swift, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am currently awaiting beta testing for my new app. I chose Fabric due to it's great reviews. However i am current getting the "Hmmm, seems like your kit isn't activating" message on the Fabric Controller after following the instruction to run the app in Xcode. I have looked around but the solutions i have found haven't made any difference.

**This is the message i am getting:**

[image: Error Image]

**This is my run script:**

[image]

**This is my info.plist:**

[image]

**And finally this is my code in the App Delegate:**

```
import UIKit
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


var window: UIWindow?

private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
    return true
}
```

**Does anyone know how to fix this error?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Don't post your unique IDs!

Comment: `cmd + b` or `cmd + r` that run script will be kicked off when you build or run the app.

Comment: And the second part you missed out (or didn't mention) is the import of data into your Info.plist. That's probably why it's not activating.

Comment: Thank you Michal, I have removed the image for the moment

Comment: @Michal I have now added my info.plist

Comment: Mike from Fabric here, try running a clean of your project, then a fresh build and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to everyone that has helped! i found the issue after going through all of my code. Swift 3 makes the App Delegate slightly confusing as i had to change my code to a `private func`or add `@nonobjc`to silence the warning

my code was originally this:

```
private func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
```

but as it was a `private func`it wasn't allowing connection with the Fabric controller

this was fixed quite easily by changing it to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the support from support@fabric.io and they helped me figure out that some else from my team has already added the same bundle id. So I just need to get the invitation.

So make sure to check this too.

Comment: how did you remove existing bundle id ?